# Functional question $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$ involving derivation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, functional-equations

I was trying to answer the following **Question:**

> Let $f$ be a function satisfying
>   $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy,\,\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
>   Suppose that $f'(a)=1+a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then show that $f'(x)=1+x\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$

One can easily notice that $f(0)=0.$ Thus, i considered two cases: $a=0$ and $a\neq0.$
For if $a=0,$ then, using the given condition for $f,$ we can easily deduce that $f'(a)=f'(0)=1$ and then it is straightforward to see that 
$$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(0)+1=x+1$$
for any $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}.$

If $a\neq0,$ then using $f'(a)=1+a$, we arrive at
$$1+a=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{f(h)}{h}+a\right)$$

My **question** is that whether one can safely deduce from this that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$ exists and $=1$ (i.e. f'(0)=1)? Do we need an additional argument on this?

[Please, forgive me if it sounds like a naive question!]

Comment: Not really. You can conclude that the limit exists AND is equal to 1 because both sides must be equal

Comment: Do you need to consider $a$ being 0 separately?

Comment: Not really. It can be done also without considering 2 cases.

Comment: Alternatively, if $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $$g(x):=f(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}$$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  This is known as Cauchy's Functional Equation.  Since $f$ is differentiable at some point, it is continuous at that point.  Therefore, $g$ is continuous at this point as well, which implies that there exists $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=kx$.  Therefore, $$f(x)=kx+\frac{x^2}{2}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $$f'(x)=k+x$$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Since $f'(a)=1+a$, we get $k=1$.